What’s the best approach to loading screens in React/Next.js without using <Suspense> or an onLoad listener?
I’m currently revamping a website I built a few years ago, updating it with newer tools and best practices I’ve picked up over the years. One blocker I'm hitting is, handling the loading screen effectively.
The idea is simple. Show a loading screen while everything (DOM, assets, animations) loads, then fade it out smoothly when the full page is ready. This is especially useful on a user’s first visit or when navigating to a new page that needs fresh data, styles, or animations.
I've tried using the react  module, it only shows the loading screen on the very first visit on any of the page, switching to another page, you can see all the glitches/pauses the loading screen is meant to hide.
<Suspense fallback={<ScreenLoader />}>
   <MyAppComponent/>
</Suspense>

I've also tried the onLoad event listener to change the loader state, for some reason it's never fired.
...
const [isLoadeing, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
...

<>
   <ScreenLoader loading={!isLoading}/>
   <div onLoad={() => setIsLoading(false)}  classname={`${isLoading && 'hidden'}`}>
      <MyAppComponent/>
   </div>
</>

I'm currently using a timed loader with setTimeout.
setTimeout(() => setIsLoader(false), 2500)


This doesn't feel right. What's the best way to go about this

depends because nextjs has lots features to approach loading states, loading UI and streaming and useSWR pending state and dynamic import has even loader property where you can put your component as skeleton loader

This is my loader by using useEffect:
"use client";

import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";

export function Loader() {
  const [routeLoading, setRouteLoading] = useState(true);

  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setRouteLoading(false);
    }, 10);
    return () => {
      setRouteLoading(true);
    };
  }, [pathname, searchParams]);

  return routeLoading && <div className="loader" />;
}

